# I want to continue with my program after opening the .bat file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to open .bat file and then continue the code but python is waiting for the end of file so I need to close the file and then it continue. But I want to open the file and continue with the code and don't close the file. thanks

```py
import os

os.system("scrcpy-console.bat")

print("continue")
```

Comment: What do you mean by `open` and `close`? You seem to be doing neither.

Comment: You may need to learn about threading for this one.

Comment: when i start the program the file "scrcpy-console.bat" will start, but it wont print continue because the file has to be close to continue so i want to the file open and print continue ( continue with the code )